# Dynamic image generation gives red x's after ~50 images

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a project that needs to generate a random collection of images on an html page. Everything works fine until around the 50th image is generated and then I just get a red X.

Am I hitting some connection limit or server resource limit?

The code below exhibits the behavior on several different machines. I am using Visual Studio 2010 and Internet Explorer.

Thanks!

HTML Page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="images">
 </div>
</body>

<script>
 var count = 0;
 function AppendImage() {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "DynamicImage.aspx?id=" + count++;
  document.getElementById("images").appendChild(img);
  img.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == "complete") {
    AppendImage()
   }
  }
 }
 AppendImage();
</script>

</html>
```

DynamicImage.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("d:\\png.png", System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
  IntPtr handle = fs.Handle;
  long size = fs.Length;
  Response.ContentType = "image/png";
  Response.WriteFile(handle, 0, size);
  fs.Close();
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Why not use Response.WriteFile(string filename)?

Comment: Using the FileStream.Handle is deprecated:
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.handle.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here turned out to be a memory problem on the client machine.  The image was of a size that when loaded ~50 times on a page caused Ineternet Explorer's memory to reach just shy of 2GB.

I verified this to be true by changing the test image to smaller and larger files and the same behavior appeared when the memory approached the 2GB mark.

Answer (score 2):

so from what i can tell this is a recursive function call that never ends. is that wise?

have you tried making a non-recursive function and see if you have better luck?

Comment: It is not the fact that it is recursive that is causing the problem.  I am just using that to demonstrate the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Response.Clear() first, and Response.End()

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Response.Clear();
System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("d:\\png.png", System.IO.FileMode.Open,     System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
IntPtr handle = fs.Handle;
long size = fs.Length;
Response.ContentType = "image/png";
Response.WriteFile(handle, 0, size);
fs.Close();
Response.End();
}
```